# Why does the DAML Multi-Party Design Pattern not output a new contract of template type Agreement?

Tags: daml

I am new to DAML and am trying to understand the multi-party agreement pattern documented in the DAML documentation @https://docs.daml.com/daml/patterns/multiparty-agreement.html .  My question is why does the Finalize choice create a ContractPlaceholder rather than having a FinalAgreement template?  It would seem, based on the notation,  that the Pending template should produce an Agreement on Finalize.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the example there is confusing. The `ContractPlaceholder` is meant to be the final agreement, so should probably be called `Agreement` instead. I've raised an issue to fix it: https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/issues/5239